# Reasonable sanction

Tags: teaching, lecturer, evaluation

A lecturer with more than 10 years of experience and proven record of excellence in both teaching and academic service failed to complete his teaching self-assessment. In general, the teaching assessment process takes into account four components:

- By students: current grade > 95%
- By program comite: current grade > 95%
- By faculty council: current grade > 95%
- By himself: current grade 0% - he forgot to answer the self-assessment.

After calculating the final grade, the lecturer failed the overall teaching evaluation.

In the absence of clear local regulation and according to your institution, what should be a reasonable sanction for this case?

1. The lecturer presents an improvement plan and continues
2. The lecturer is suspended for 1 semester, presents an improvement plan and continues
3. The lecturer is suspended permanently and can continue only after a new hiring process

I’m not saying the local institution selected option 3!

Comment: I'll suspect that if option 3 was chosen that there were other reasons and this was just the "final straw". But in general, both 2 and 3 seem unreasonable to me, unless repeated.

Comment: If you suspend lecturers (who favour research), then surely more lecturers (who favour research) will "forget" to answer the self-assessment.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Your lecture forgot to fill out some self-evalustion and you ask how to punish him reasonably, right?

Comment: Maybe that guy *wants* sanction 2 or 3, so he can appeal to the higher administration, and reveal (in his opinion) how pointless the requirement is.

Comment: What is the self-assessment actually used for? Is it actually used for anything other then checking a box? Instead of a self-assessment, would a 15 minute chat with the department chair or dean be more worthwhile?

Comment: @user111955 Yes, you can assume in the way you state it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't sanction; just ask the lecturer to complete their self-assessment and re-compute their overall teaching evaluation.

In the future, consider introducing a process that prevents lecturers forgetting to complete the self-assessment, e.g., by asking for the assessment more than once.

Comment: Some degree of sanction is probably required, though, otherwise what incentive do they have to actually complete their self-assessment on time? If you don’t take it seriously, why should they?

Comment: @nick012000, could you please give examples of "some degree of sanction"?

Comment: @nick012000 The lecturer cannot complete on time, we're in recovery mode. In the future, lecturers can complete on time, using the mechanism I propose.

Comment: _Some degree of sanction is probably required, though_ — Why?  If the other evaluations are stellar, why is the self-evaluation necessary?

Comment: As @JeffE perhaps suggests, this seems less about useful evaluation of teaching than it is about obedience to rules... possibly beyond a point at which the rules make sense.

Comment: I think @nick012000 may have found the perfect solution with "If you don't take it seriously, why should they?" I suggest that you not take it seriously and that you publicly announce that you will not take it seriously in the future. Presumably lecturers will then not take it seriously either and there will be no more of these self-assessments. I regard that result as an improvement of the system.